# How to create div with text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to grab text inside a page, and put it inside a div/span element using jQuery.

For example, grab `<p>Did you know "LARC" is a Medical Term?</p>` off a webpage and put it inside of a div like so: `<p>Did you know <div class="LARC IS COOL">"LARC"</div> is a Medical Term?</p>`

The reason I am asking is because I need to run a function on a specific word with a class but I don't have access to the html where that word is due to the fact it comes from an outside source and is loaded on the page.

This is what I currently have:

```
jQuery('.gfield_label').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).text(text.replace("LARC", "<div class='LARC IS COOL'>LARC</div>")); 
});
```

But it just outputs this on the webpage:

```
Did you know <div title='THIS BETTER WORK'>LARC</div> is a medical term?
```

Comment: You can't access cross-origin frames, if that content you're talking about is iframed.

Comment: It's rendered through a Plugin, not a iframe. Good point though.

Comment: If the content is added to your page, and not in an iframe or object tag, you do have access to it. What wouldn't work is (undelegated) event handlers for elements that are added later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using .text(), try using .html().

Comment: I swear to god I tried this and it didn't work, but decided to give it another shot and it did. Thanks man, will add you as an answer when the time limit goes up.

Comment: Ahah alright thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the HTML function when replacing.

see: http://api.jquery.com/text/ and
http://api.jquery.com/html/

```js
jQuery('.gfield_label').each(function() {
    var text = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).html(text.replace("LARC", "<div class='LARC IS COOL'>LARC</div>")); 
});
```

Comment: Don't understand why this was voted down, it was a correct solution. I voted you back up.